# DIF between keepass and MEPM

Tags: microsoft-edge

I'm curious about the pros and cons of the microsoft edge password manager, and the technical differences between keepass (password safe).

what are your preferences and why

Comment: This question is not a suitable question for Stack Overflow, as it's both a primarily opinion-based question, and is not about programming. Once you're able to make this question not primarily opinion-based, you may be able to get an answer from the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange site, but please make sure that your question is [on-topic](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and that you read their [question quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336) before posting there.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with keepass. But keepass is a software and Edge password manager is built in Edge browser. I think that's the biggest difference.

For how Edge password manager provides security for user passwords and other detailed information about Edge password manager, you can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-security-password-manager-security).